# change identity routing in asp.net core 3.1 from Identity/Account/Register to /Register

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I want to change the routing system identity in asp.net core 3.1 from
Identity/Account/Register
to this
/register
/login
What should I do?

Comment: Hi @RezaShakeri, any update?

Comment: @Yinqiu yes , change url site

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @Yinqiu yes my friend, thanks for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code in your `Identity/Account/Register.cshtml` to

```
@page "/Register"
```

Comment: Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes